# Change part of the pathname in url using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, url, localization

I am working in an application where I am using localization. For localization both admin and user can change the language. If admin changed recently, that change will be affected to all users.

For Ex, Admin changed the language to en-US, so the url will be http://localhost:81/en-US/form

Then, If user trying to change the language, http://localhost:81/fr-fr/form like this, we need to redirect to http://localhost:81/en-US/form. I need to change that part alone in pathname.

I have tried like,

```
 if (!data.Status) 
 {
  // data.Data contains ("en-US") this part of url
  var URL = window.location;
  URL.replace("/" + data.Data, "/" + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]);
 }
```

So, Url changing like http://localhost:81/en-US not http://localhost:81/en-US/form.

If I try this in c# url will be like, url wil be like http://localhost:81/controller/view?languagetag=en-US/something

How can I change this part alone ??

Any idea to achieve this in script or suggest me to do in C#.